# ¿Cómo filtrar una gráfica por grupo en ggplot2?

Tags: r, rstudio, ggplot2

Tengo la siguiente gráfica que mediante `facet_wrap` lo que hago es mostrar en grupos, según los valores que tenga la columna `X4` (de tipo `factor`), unas gráficas de barras con los valores que hay en la columna `X6`, que es otro tipo de dato `factor`.

Esta gráfica además muestra los valores relativos en función del total de registros, el `data frame` no tiene más de 100 registros.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora bien, realmente lo que quisiera hacer es mostrar esta misma gráfica pero sólo con los dos casos que más volumen tienen, es decir, los dos primeros grupos, porque el resto desearía despreciarlo en la gráfica, que no en el `data frame`, porque no tienen realmente volumen con los que poder trabajar.

El código que tengo para mostrar la gráfica es el siguiente:

```
ggplot(df, aes(X6)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..), fill = as.factor(X6))) +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent((..count..)/sum(..count..)),
            y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)),
            check_overlap = TRUE,
            stat = "count",
            vjust = 1,
            hjust = .3,
            size = 2.5) +
  facet_wrap(~X4, scales = "free", nrow = 2) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  xlab(element_blank()) +
  ylab(element_blank()) +
  ggtitle("Título") +
  labs(fill = "Leyenda") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
    axis.text = element_text(size = 8),
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)
  )
```

He probado añadiendo en el `geom_bar` un `group = c("valor1", "valor2")` pero no me filtra la gráfica mostrando los dos grupos que me interesarían.

Por otra parte lo que estoy viendo es que los ratios están mal calculados porque no se relativizan según el grupo, en la segunda gráfica por ejemplo la suma no da 100%, y en el resto de gráficas las etiquetas no se asemejan con el eje y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los datos debes filtrarlos antes de que lleguen a `ggplot` ya que este no tiene ninguna funcionalidad de manipulación de los mismos. Puedes hacerlo al vuelo, de forma tal de no "tocar" el `data.frame` original:

```
library(dplyr)

ggplot(data = filter(df, X4 %in% c(1, 3)), 
       mapping = aes(X6)) +
...
```

Con respecto al problema de los porcentajes, ahora están calculados en función del total y no por grupo. En mi caso yo prefiero construir un `data.frame` con los porcentajes precalculados, me resultan algo confuso hacerlo desde la funciones estadísticas de `ggplot` además que me resulta más cómodo tener materializados los datos para controlarlos, sin embargo, [he visto que se puede](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49566235/6836377), en tu caso deberías ajustar las barras y el texto del procentaje:

```
  geom_bar(aes(y =  ..count../tapply(..count.., ..x.. ,sum)[..x..], fill = as.factor(X6))) +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent( ..count../tapply(..count.., ..x.. ,sum)[..x..]),
                y = ..count../tapply(..count.., ..x.. ,sum)[..x..]),
                check_overlap = TRUE,
                stat = "count",
                vjust = 1,
                hjust = .3,
                size = 2.5
```